# How to color <area> on absoulute positioned canvas

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

**This is what I want to do:**

- I want to color the polygons given by the coordinates in the map for the image when you hover over the polygons defined by the area elements. I also want the image to have a dynamic size (width in percent).

I've tried using `rwdImageMaps` to recalculate the coordinates for the image once it's re-sized. This works to the extent that the pointer cursor seems to appear on the correct place.

**Problem:**

Drawing the coordinates on to the canvas causes the polygons to appear in the wrong place.

Here's how the HTML looks like:

```
<div style="width:80%;height:350px;margin:auto;position:relative;">
    <img id="MyImg" src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/80000/nahled/3d-shape-icons.jpg" usemap="#Map" style="overflow:hidden;" />
    <canvas id="map_canvas" style="z-index: 10;pointer-events: none;"/>
    <map name="Map" id="MyMap">
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="20,7,12,22,19,49,19,76,13,92,17,110,41,118,67,112,101,118,132,109,131,86,124,61,130,36,132,13,109,4,77,13,58,10,37,2,28,3,15,14" />
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="184,17,181,33,185,52,174,62,165,82,178,95,200,99,208,115,219,126,245,116,254,99,267,98,286,90,289,66,272,53,270,33,271,16,258,8,238,13,234,21,227,19,208,9,193,12" />
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="349,8,333,18,322,44,316,62,327,88,342,111,364,121,402,121,427,106,437,81,442,60,439,40,424,11,395,2,366,2" />
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="501,7,479,34,470,49,472,78,480,103,527,128,577,107,589,48,557,7" />
    </map>
</div>
```

The solution doesn't have to use `rwdImageMaps`.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cojvyu17/4/)

Comment: This is because you never set the canvas width/ height.  https://jsfiddle.net/cojvyu17/9/ Canvas has its own coordinate matrix, don't set its width/height through CSS or you'll have problems like that. Currently, it was a 300x150px frame, stretched to 396x350px. When you drawn  at 501, it obviously had issues

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion it was something like this, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to post that as a answer?

Comment: No, there are dupes and it's unfortunately unlikely to help anyone in the future... (since you didn't found those dupes)